# Line-break and superscript in axis label ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a graph in ggplot2.
The label on y axis should include a line break and text in superscript, and should be centered.
It should look like:

"Density of mobile 
invertebrates (indiv. m^-2)"

The line break should be after "mobile" and the "per square m" should be in superscript. 
I've tried

```
p+ ylab(bquote("Density of mobile\ninvertebrates"(indiv.~m^-2)))
```

but it is not centered and there's a funny space before the "(indiv.~m^-2)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `expression()` and `atop()` to autoformat white space.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   xlab( expression(atop("Density of mobile",paste("invertebrates (ind.~",m^{2},")"))))
```

[image]

**Data**

```
set.seed(1) 
data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10 + runif(-1,1,n=10))
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify the space between the lines? I join some plots together using cowplot. Some of the other plots have less space between the lines, as they are coded with "\n". e.g.  p + ylab(bquote("Habitat\nfunctional richness"))

Comment: You could just change those to be `expression(atop("Habitat","functional richness"))`. And if your OCD is really making you worry about the size, you can call `atop` on one line axis labels with a second blank string. For example `expression(atop("Niche",""))`.